# Blender doesn't use RAM, CPU, and GPU of PC

Tags: cycles-render-engine, edit-mode, eevee-render-engine

In the Blender Editor, it really lags (cycles and eevee). But it only uses Max. 15 % of CPU, Max. 10 % of RAM and 0 % of GPU. Why? It could be much faster. Please help

Comment: Have you copied the OpenGL DLL into the Blender directory? That results in software rendering which is very slow.

Comment: It can't find my GPU. I have no OpenGl.dll on my system.

Comment: If you are able to start Blender it recognizes your GPU, otherwise it wouldn't start at all. If you have multiple GPUs (e.g. an integrated GPU in your CPU and a dedicated GPU) you may be able to select which one is used by default for e.g. OpenGL drawing. On Windows this can be done as described in [T78799](https://developer.blender.org/T78799).

Comment: If you want to use GPU rendering for Cycles, then you have to select the GPUs in *Edit > Preferences > System*. Your GPU has to meet the [minimum requirements for GPU rendering](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/cycles/gpu_rendering.html#supported-hardware) to be listed. Please note that the Task Manager does not display CUDA activity by default, thus is may look like your GPU isn't busy when it actually is.